Tic Tac Toe using React - how to color only winning buttons?
I have a Tic Tac Toe game in React that works fine, it correctly shows the winner. But if for instance, Player X is winning, it's coloring with green all the X tiles, not just the winning ones.
I want to color with green only the winning tiles.
I know it doesn't work with DOM manipulation, I tried using a color in state, but it also colors all the tiles.
This is the Main Component, that holds the state:
export default function Grid() {
    // Game state
    const [grid, setGrid] = useState(new Array(9).fill(""));
    const [turn, setTurn] = useState("P1") //toggle turns for P1 and P2
    const [color, setColor] = useState("black")
    
    // Players state
    const [countWinP1, setCountWinP1] = useState(0)
    const [countWinP2, setCountWinP2] = useState(0)

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        const clickValue = event.target.value
        
        setGrid(grid.map((btn, index) => {
            if (index+1 == clickValue && turn === "P1") {
                return btn = "X"
            } else if (index+1 == clickValue && turn === "P2") {
                return btn = "0"
            }
            return btn
        }))
        handleToggle();
    }
    

    // WIN COUNT
    useEffect(() => {
        const newCountP1 = countWinP1 + 1;
        const newCountP2 = countWinP2 + 1;
        if (handleWinner(grid) && turn === "P2") {
            setCountWinP1(newCountP1); 
        } else
        if (handleWinner(grid) && turn === "P1") {
            setCountWinP2(newCountP2); 
        }
    }, [grid]);

    // RESETS
    const handleToggle = () => {
        if (turn === "P1") {
            setTurn("P2")
        } else {
            setTurn("P1")
        }         
    }
    const handleReset = () => {
        setGrid(new Array(9).fill(0));
        setTurn("P1")
    }
    const handlePlayersReset = () => {
        setCountWinP1(0)
        setCountWinP2(0)
    }


    return (
        <>
        <WinCount countWinP1={countWinP1} countWinP2={countWinP2} PlayersReset={handlePlayersReset}/>
        <Box grid={grid} handleClick={handleClick} handleWinner={handleWinner(grid)} handleReset={handleReset} turn={turn} color={color}/>     
    </>
  )
}

This is the Box component:
export default function Box({grid, handleClick, handleWinner, handleReset, turn, color}) {

  return (
    <>
     <div className='container'>
        <h1>
            {handleWinner && turn==="P2" ? "WINNER: PLAYER 1" : handleWinner && turn==="P1" ? "WINNER: PLAYER 2" : "GAME ON"}
        </h1>

     
        <div className='box'>
           {grid.map((btn, index) => {
                if (btn === "X") {
                    return <button id={index+1} key={uuid()} value={index+1} onClick={handleClick} disabled={true}><strong style={{fontSize:30, color: handleWinner && turn=== "P2"? "green" : handleWinner && turn=== "P1" ? "red" : "black" }}>X</strong></button>
                        } else 
                if (btn === "0") {
                    return <button id={index+1} key={uuid()} value={index+1} onClick={handleClick} disabled={true}><strong style={{fontSize:30, color: handleWinner && turn=== "P1"? "green" : handleWinner && turn=== "P2" ? "red" : "black" }}>0</strong></button>
                        } else  
                    return <button id={index+1} key={uuid()} value={index+1} onClick={handleClick} disabled={handleWinner? true : false}>Click me</button>
                    })}
        </div>

        <button className="grid_reset" onClick={handleReset}>RESET</button>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}


What specific logic observes the selected squares and determines the winner?  I would imagine that logic could record which squares were used to determine the "winning" state, no?

I have a handleWinner function, something like:
export function handleWinner (grid) {
if (grid[0] === "X" && grid[0] === grid[1] && grid[0] === grid[2]) {
return true
} else
if (grid[0] === "X" && grid[0] === grid[3] && grid[0] === grid[6]) {
return true
going through all the winning combos, but when applied to the squares, it colors all squares of the winner, not just the winning combo squares.

Well, how do you identify the winning combo squares?  In your logic that checks if there is a winner, can you use that information to determine the squares to highlight?  Currently that function returns a boolean value only indicating if the player won.  It doesn't return anything indicating which squares the player used to win.  Return that information and use it in the component to highlight those specific squares.

Thank you for your input! I changed my winning  function to determine the specific squares and now it works. I was overthinking it. thanks again!
